# How to freez for 1 in the middle of execution method Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

```
def changeText(self, instance):
    instance.text = "Submit"

def btn(self, instance):
    print("Name: ", self.name.text, "Surname: ", self.surname.text, " | Email", self.email.text)
    self.name.text = ""
    self.surname.text = ""
    self.email.text = ""
    instance.text = "Submitted"
    Clock.schedule_once(self.changeText(instance), 1)
```

I need just a change button name 1 sec after will clicked. I have tried Time.sleep() etc. but it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.changeText(instance), 1)
```

This is *calling* changeText, not scheduling it. Consider that what you've written is the same as:

```
result = self.changeText(instance)  # result is None
Clock.schedule_once(result, 1)
```

This obviously doesn't schedule anything.

Instead you need to schedule a function that does what you want, e.g.:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.changeText(instance), 1)
```